# Joda DateTime Invalid format

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to get the current DateTime with my DateTimeFormat pattern, but i'm getting the exception...

```
//sets the current date
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm").withLocale(locale);
DateTime now = dtf.parseDateTime(currentDate.toString());
```

I'm getting this exception, I cannot understand who is giving the malformed format

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2017-01-04T14:24:17.674+01:00" is malformed at "17-01-04T14:24:17.674+01:00"
```

Comment: Are you trying to format the date as a string or are you trying to parse a string into a datetime object?

Comment: It should be a DateTime object

Comment: But you're *starting* with a `DateTime` - why convert it to text and back at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `DateTime now = dtf.parseDateTime(currentDate.toString());` isn't correct because you try parse date with default toSring format. You have to parse string which formatted the same way as pattern:

```
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm").withLocale(locale);
String formatedDate = dtf.print(currentDate);
System.out.println(formatedDate);
DateTime now = dtf.parseDateTime(formatedDate);
System.out.println(now);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format to parse the date. If you print out the date you are trying to parse after converting it to a String with `toString` you get:

```
2017-01-04T14:24:17.674+01:00
```

This date string does not conform to the pattern `dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm`. To parse the to a string converted `currentDate` to a `DateTime` object again, you have to use the following pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                                      .withLocale(locale);
```

Parsing with this `DateTimeFormatter` will get you another instance that represents the same time as the original `currentDate`.

For more details on the `DateTimeFormatter` and it's parsing options check out the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)