# Parse exception in joda-time parsing day and time

Tags: java, jodatime

The problem is pretty simple, I have a TimerTask that is going to be scheduled daily or weekly. (Depends on the given start date and period in config file).
So in config file I specify the day of week and time of execution with period between executions. But Joda-Time refuses to work with my date :(

Here is basic input:

```
String            input     = "Tue 12:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(input, formatter); // Here parse exception is thrown...
```

Exception message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Tue 12:00:00"`

Could someone explain me why I cannot parse this date like that and maybe point me into right direction to solve this kind of problem. Of course I could manually parse the date and set things in calendar, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is something like Joda-Time that could do it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weekday text `Tue` probably doesnt match that of your default locale.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Another question, can I somehow set this date relative to current week or date? So when I want Tuesday it will be next Tuesday from today? Thanks for help.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to add 1 week to the date, i.e. `dateTime.plusWeeks(1)`

Comment: Well not really, date after parsing `Tue 12:00:00` appears to be: `2000-12-26T12:00:00.000+01:00`.

Comment: You havent supplied any date element (day, month. year) in your initial date so Jodatime is using one from the year `2000`

Comment: I kinda solved this problem: Just took `DateTime.now().withDayOfWeek(...).withTime(...)` where I supply information from parsed DateTime I get from config file :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use Locale. The following code is working fine.

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test22 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatedDate = dtf.print(currentDate);
        System.out.println(formatedDate);
        DateTime now = dtf.parseDateTime(formatedDate);
        System.out.println(now);
    }

}
```

### Output:

> Thu 23:36:33
>
> 2000-12-28T23:36:33.000+06:00

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465180/2293534